# how do you set up log4j for a gradle project with modules?

Tags: gradle, log4j

how do you set up log4j for a gradle project with modules?

I have a project set up like the following:

```
project root
build.gradle
gradle.properties
settings.gradle
// this root project does:
// include CommonModule
// includeBuild <all composite modules within module folder>

---CommonModule
------build.gradle
------gradle.properties
------settings.gradle
------src/main/groovy/...<common-code>
------src/main/resources/log4j2.xml

Modules
---OtherModule-1 
// this is a gradle composite module
// it also includes the common module 
------build.gradle
------gradle.properties
------settings.gradle
------src/main/groovy/...module1-code
------src/main/resources/log4j2.xml
---OtherModule-2 
// this is a gradle composite module
// it also includes the common module 
------build.gradle
------gradle.properties
------settings.gradle
------src/main/groovy/...module2-code
------src/main/resources/log4j2.xml
```

As shown above, we have a common gradle module and a module folder that contains module related composite module, each which depends on the included CommonModule
(core common code goes in common, the composite modules each contain code that extends common stuff

My question is hopefully simple:

- where do I configure my log4j module?
- e.g. can I put it in the common include module ?
- or does each composite module need to have their own log4j xml?

Comment: see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went and asked this same question on the gradle forums https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-you-set-up-log4j-for-a-gradle-project-with-modules/28262 and got an answer -

- Common module doesn’t include a log4j config Individual library
- modules don’t include a log4j config either Top-level application
- module does include a log4j config, but doesn’t put it on the
  classpath (I set aside a src/[configuration]/config directory just
  for that)
- Launcher for the application itself (whether from a release
  build or from a JavaExec in the Gradle build) specifies where the
  log4j config is loaded from, so that you can’t get accidentally
  poisoned by other configs on the classpath
- you can define the xml location by providing a -D flag in the gradle properties file e.g. -Dlog4j.configurationFile=
- also -Dlog4j.debug might help to track down issues